# Composing gmail messages in text editor complete with gmail links

Tags: emacs, gmail

I like to compose messages in Emacs then copy/paste into gmail for sending. I often want to include in the body of the message a link or links to other web sites. In gmail's compose dialog box I can click on the Insert Link button then enter the text to display and the URL for the link. I want to achieve the same effect in Emacs. I thought a standard `<a href>` link might work, like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

but gmail doesn't seem to interpret that as it would be here on SO, for example. Obviously, the string `http://www.google.com` is recognised as a link, but I would like to be able to specify the text.

I have found many posts on the use of `mailto` link but not on inserting URLs. Maybe I've missed something obvious, but is there any way to achieve this? Some kind of markup that works?

Comment: Although not an answer to your question, it is possible to receive and send e-mails with Emacs using gmail -- without using an internet browser.

Comment: A wild guess: you could try composing your messages in org-mode, export that to HTML, open the HTML file in a browser, and copy-paste into Gmail.  That _might_ preserve the links...

Answer (score 2):

[`gmail-message-mode`](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/gmail-mode) was designed for exactly this use case:

> **gmail-message-mode** is an emacs major-mode for editing Gmail messages using markdown syntax, it is meant for use with browser plugins which allow you to edit text fields with external applications (in this case, emacs).

1. Install an [appropriate editor plugin](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/gmail-mode#plugins) for your browser:

   > ### Plugins
   >
   > 1. **Google-Chrome** or **Chromium** - [Edit with emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Edit_with_Emacs)
   > 2. **Conkeror** - [Spawn Helper (built-in)](http://conkeror.org/ConkerorSpawnHelper)
   > 3. **Firefox** - Used to work with [It's all text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/). See [this thread](https://github.com/docwhat/itsalltext/issues/36) for a hacky workaround.
   > 4. *Others* - Tried it in another browser? [let me know](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/gmail-message-mode/issues/new)!

   There will also be some Emacs configuration, depending on the plugin you choose. For instance, to get Edit with Emacs working, I have `edit-server` installed, and make sure to enable it on startup with `(edit-server-start)`.
2. Install `gmail-message-mode` from MELPA or MELPA stable.

   `ham-mode` ("HTML as Markdown") takes care of the Markdown / HTML translation for `gmail-message-mode`, so you will also have to configure `ham-mode`'s `ham-mode-markdown-command` to something appropriate.

   I usually have [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) installed, and use something like this:

   ```lisp
   (setf ham-mode-markdown-command
     '("/usr/bin/pandoc" "--from" "markdown" "--to" "html" "--standalone" file))
   ```
3. Open up a Gmail editing window and trigger the Emacs plugin. For Edit with Emacs, I right-click the message section and select "Edit with Emacs".
4. Switch to Emacs and edit your message in Markdown format. When you're done, `C-x #`.

   A short test message might look like this:

   ```lisp
   Test **message** *using* [gmail-message-mode](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/gmail-mode).
   ```

   Which renders, correctly, like this in Gmail:

   > Test **message** *using* [gmail-message-mode](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/gmail-mode).

This might seem like a lot of work, but if you've alredy got a plugin configured to edit `textarea`s in Emacs like I had, it's really not much of a change.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I looked into `gmail-message-mode` before I posted this question and concluded - as you foresaw - that it would be a lot of work, particularly as Firefox is my default browser.

Answer (score 1):

Use [org-mime](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-mime.html).

You can enter the links in org-mode format like this:

```
[[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046646/composing-gmail-messages-in-text-editor-complete-with-gmail-links][Composing gmail messages in text editor]]
```

Then use the org-mime function `org-mime-htmlize` to convert the message to HTML, including the links.